# Appending my sessionId to an arrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

Each time a new session id is created i need to save them in an array or a list, to have it as a reference.

Correct me where am i wrong

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

//creating an arrayList 

ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();

try { 

// calculate the sessionId 

String sessionId = "b03c0-000-5h6-" + uuid.substring(0,4) + "-000000000";
myList.add(sessionId);

} catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

the elements in my arrayList are getting replaced and not appended.

Where am i wrong

Comment: how did you assert that the elements are getting replaced?

Comment: The element in the `ArrayList` is not replaced, the full `ArrayList` is replaced everytime you call the main method! Then it looks like the element is replaced.

Comment: String sessionId = "b03c0-000-5h6-" + uuid.substring(0,4) + "-000000000";
myList.add(sessionId); this put in loop other when you call main() it replace full arraylist

Answer (score 1):

You are wrong.

The [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) interface is designed store the values with duplicates. So you will append. If you want only unique results use [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) instead.

`Collection<String> myList = new HashSet<String>();`

Note that List and Set are math concepts that both represent collections. In [Java Collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/) Framework those concepts ware reproduces as classes and interfaces.

The `Collection<T>` is the super interfaces of Set and List. This allow you to change the behavior of your program depending on implementation.

You should also avoid using class names in variables, to have that flexibility.

If you want to "tell" other developers that the session ids storage store only unique values use

`Set<String> sessionsIDs = new HashSet<String>();`

If you want to "tell", that storage is in form of list (that allow repetitions) use

`List<String> sessionsIDs = new ArrayList<String>();`

---

If you want to keep that detail of implementation hidden, use collection

```
Collection<String> sessionsID = crateSessionStorage();

private Collection<String> crateSessionStorage() {

    boolean useUniqueStorage = isUniqueStorage(); 

    if(UseUniqueStorage) {
       return new HashSet<String>();
    }

    return new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

Comment: @Maroun Maroun What that change ?

Comment: Your code is fine, but it's not encouraged to be that extreme, `Set` is enough as an *interface* (If you prefer this style you can rollback - sorry for inconvenience).

Comment: I was i middle of edit. But curious why. In that state you had right with that edit. So no apologize needed. Have a nice day ;-).

Answer (score 0):

The creation/initialization of myList in your code results to undesired behavior.

Your ArrayList can be a static instance attribute of your class instead of getting created everytime the method is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

```
 String sessionId = "b03c0-000-5h6-" + uuid.substring(0,4) + "-000000000"; myList.add(sessionId); this put in loop other when you call main() it replace full arraylis
```

Comment: public static ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>(); // As per me this should work.. but got an error, invalid identifier for public static..

Comment: because you declare your array inside static main() you should declare arraylist outside main() or before main()

Answer (score -2):

It is happening because you are creating every time new object

```
ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>(); // creates an object evrytime whem main will be called.

 try { 
String sessionId = "b03c0-000-5h6-" + uuid.substring(0,4)
/* from where uuid is comming?? */
 + "-000000000";
        myList.add(sessionId); 
// thiss will add inside new arraylist not in previous,
// because everytime it is getting new object reference
  } catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
   }

        }
```

Comment: `main` is called once.

Comment: ^ Yeah but the call to "new" might be in a for loop.

Comment: @Maroun - No, we do not see the entire code. Do you see where uuid is defined?

Comment: @Maroun - You dont declare class members inside the main method

Comment: @EmanuelSaringan I said it's a class member. I didn't say it was declared in `main`.

Comment: it isnt in a for loop.

Comment: how else can he call the try-catch block where the id is added without calling the arraylist instatiation? if this is really the full code, he call main again.

Comment: @user1333420 pls tell us how you add a new id if its not in a loop?

Comment: @Maroun - But the asker placed it inside the main method with some code in between (omitted using the comments)

Comment: @ashish you should see the above comment of user1333420. He posted it.

Comment: So how can I tell tell this. He is the one who program this. :D

Comment: Down vote as your answer has noting in common with the question.